# Burger button doesn't seem to work at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have a burger menu when the screen is small enough however it doesn't react like a button at all, more like an image. I have compared it to other snippets of code and other solutions found on here but I can't find a solution. I have added the code I have currently. I have provided the HTML (the first section), css (the second section) and Javascript (the third section)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charsets="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal projects Website | Chris McClure</title>

    <!-- ----BOX ICONS---- -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


    <!-- ----CUSTOM CSS---- -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    

    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">projects</a>

        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></i>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About Me</a>
            <a href="#education">Education</a>
            <a href="#projects">projects</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- ----HOME SECTION DESIGN---- -->
    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="home-content">
            <h3>Hello, It's Me</h3>
            <h1>Chris McClure</h1>
            <h3>And I'm a <span class="multiple-text"></span></h3>
            <p>I have had a wide range of experiences. I am also drawn to learning about new innovative tech</p>
            <div class="social-media">
                <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin-square'></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-github' ></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Download CV</a>
        </div>

        <div class="home-img">
            <img src="/images/Logo-face.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- ---- ABOUT SECTION---- -->
    <section class="about" id="about">
        <div class="about-img">
            <img src="images/Me.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="about-content">
            <h2 class="heading">About <span>Me</span></h2>
            <h3>Systems Engineer/Software Testing/Security Analyst/IT Enthusiast</h3>
            <p>I am the type of person always looking to learn something new, improve my own skills and expand them.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- ----EDUCATION SECTION---- -->
    <section class="education" id="education">
        <h2 class="heading">My <span>Education</span></h2>

        <div class="education-container">
            <div class="education-box">
                <i class='bx bx-water' ></i>
                <h3>Systems Engineer</h3>
                <p>Providing support for a 24/7 control room that monitors water dams and wind farms to generate electricity</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="education-box">
                <i class='bx bx-desktop'></i>
                <h3>Hardware Tester/Agency Worker</h3>
                <p>testing the functionality and integrity of a variety of tech from TV's, phones, laptops, PC's and much more for an auction house.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="education-box">
                <i class='bx bxs-pizza' ></i>
                <h3>Delivery Driver</h3>
                <p>Delivering pizza was the main part of the role while also supporting those in the shop with packaging food and cleaning the shop.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- ----projects SECTION---- -->
    <section class="projects" id="projects">
        <h2 class="heading">Latest <span>Project</span></h2>

        <div class="projects-container">
            <div class="projects-box">
                <img src="images/Webscraper-git.png" alt="">
                <div class="projects-layer">
                    <h4>Python Web Scraper</h4>
                    <p>program to scrape data from the Marvel website</p>
                    <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-python' ></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="projects-box">
                <img src="images/marvel-website.png" alt="">
                <div class="projects-layer">
                    <h4>WIX Website Design</h4>
                    <p>MARVEL Fan Website</p>
                    <a href=""><i class='bx bxl-python' ></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="projects-box">
                <img src="images/first-website.png" alt="">
                <div class="projects-layer">
                    <h4>First HTML Website</h4>
                    <p>First HTML Website built at University</p>
                    <a href=""><i class='bx bxl-python' ></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- ----CONTACT SECTION---- -->
    <section class="contact" id="contact">
        <h2 class="heading">Contact <span>Me!</span></h2>

        <form action="#">
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
                <input class="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn">
        </form>
    </section>

    <!-- ----FOOTER SECTION---- -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-text">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2023 by Chris | All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-iconTop">
            <a href="#home"><i class='bx bx-up-arrow-alt'></i></a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- ----SCROLL REVEAL---- -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

    <!-- ----TYPED JS---- -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/typed.js@2.0.15/dist/typed.umd.js"></script>

    
    
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --bg-color: #1f242d;
    --second-bg-color: #323946;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #ff004f;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10rem 9%;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 9%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.header.sticky {
    border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.logo {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: default;
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin-left: 4rem;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover, .navbar a.active {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

#menu-icon {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    display: none;
}

.home {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.home-img img {
    width: 35vw;
    animation: floatImage 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes floatImage {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-2.4);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.home-content h3 {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.home-content h3:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

span {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.home-content h1 {
    font-size: 5.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.home-content p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.social-media a {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    background: transparent;
    border: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin: 3rem 1.5rem 3rem 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.social-media a:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--second-bg-color);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem var(--main-color);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2.8rem;
    background: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 4rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem var(--main-color);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: var(--second-bg-color);
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.about{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    background: ver(--second-bg-color);
}

.about-img img{
    width: 35vw;
}

.heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.about-content h2 {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.about-content h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.about-content p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: 2rem 0 3rem;
}

.education h2 {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.education-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.education-container .education-box {
    flex: 1 1 30rem;
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
    padding: 3rem 2rem 4rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: .2rem solid var(--bg-color);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.education-container, .education-box:hover {
    border-color: var(--main-color);
    transform: scale(1.02);
}

.education-box i {
    font-size: 7rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.education-box h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.education-box p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: 1rem 0 3rem;
}

.projects {
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
}

.projects h2 {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.projects-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2.5rem;
}

.projects-container, .projects-box {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem var(--bg-color);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.projects-box img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.projects-box:hover img {
    transform: scale(.8);
}

.projects-box .projects-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), var(--main-color));
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.projects-box:hover .projects-layer {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.projects-layer h4 {
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.projects-layer p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: .3rem 0 1rem;
}

.projects-layer a {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: var(--text-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.projects-layer a i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--second-bg-color);
}

.contact h2 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.contact form {
    max-width: 70rem;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.contact form .input-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contact form .input-box input, 
.contact form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
    border-radius: .8rem;
    margin: .7rem 0;
}
.contact form .input-box input {
    width: 49%;
}
.contact form textarea {
    resize: none;
}
.contact form .btn {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 2rem 9%;
    background: var(--second-bg-color);
}
.footer-text p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.footer-iconTop a {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .8rem;
    background: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: .8rem;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.footer-iconTop a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem var(--main-color);
}
.footer-iconTop a i {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: var(--second-bg-color);
}

/* ----BREAKPOINTS---- */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    html {
        font-size: 55%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .header {
        padding: 2rem 3%;
    }
    section {
        padding: 10rem 3% 2rem;
    }
    .education {
        padding-bottom: 7rem;
    }
    .education {
        padding-bottom: 7rem;
    }
    .contact{
        min-height: auto;
    }
    .footer {
        padding: 2rem 3%;
    }
} 

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem 3%;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar.active {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 3rem 0;
    }
    .home {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .home-content h3 {
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    .home-content h1 {
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
    .home-img img {
        width: 70vw;
        margin-top: 4rem;
    }
    .about {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .about-img {
        width: 70vw;
        margin-top: 4rem;
    }
    .education h2 {
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    .education h2 {
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    .education-container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1f);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 617px){
    .education-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media (max-width:450px) {
    html {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
    .contact form .input-box input {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 365px) {
    .home-img img {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    .about-img img {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    .footer {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .footer p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
}
```

```
/* ----SCROLL SECTION ACTIVE LINK---- */
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('header nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => {
        let top = window.scrollY;
        let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
        let height = sec.offsetHeight;
        let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

        if(top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
            navLinks.forEach(links => {
                links.classList.remove('active');
                document.querySelector('header nav a[href*=' + id + ']').classList.add('active');
            });
        };
    });
    /* ----STICKY NAVBAR---- */
    let header = document.querySelector('header');

    header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 100);

    /* ----REMOVE TOGGLE ICON AND NAVBAR WHEN CLICK NAVBAR LINK (SCROLL)---- */
    menuIcon.classList.remove('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.remove('active');
};

 /* ----SCROLL REVEAL---- */
 ScrollReveal({ 
    reset: true,
    distance: '80px',
    duration: 2000,
    delay: 200
});

ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content, .heading', { origin: 'top' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-img, .education, .container, .portfolio-box, .contact form', { origin: 'bottom' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content h1, .about-img', { origin: 'left' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content p, .about-content', { origin: 'right' });

/* ----TYPED JS---- */
const typed = new Typed('.multiple-text', {
    strings: ['Systems Engineer', 'IT Enthusiast'],
    typeSpeed: 100,
    backSpeed: 100,
    backDelay: 1000,
    loop: true
});

/* ----TOGGLE ICON NAVBAR---- */
let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

MenuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined it in small letter and you're calling it with capital letter

Wrong:

```
let menuIcon ... MenuIcon.onclick
```

Correct:

```
let MenuIcon ... MenuIcon.onclick
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been hunting for a few hours on what was wrong. sometimes its good to have a fresh set of eyes look at it. I really appreciate the time you took to help :)

Comment: Welcome bro, I have to say your code is the most cleanest code I have read, keep going man and good luck 

Comment: I try to keep it clean. I am now working on creating separate pages for more detail on experiences, projects etc. However, the burger stops working on these haha. I have a file structure where css and js have their own folders. ill make another post for that part.

Comment: @ChristopherMcClure , mention me when you post maybe I can help